# React Router - Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I am building a styleguide app. I have two dropdown components where a user can choose both a brand and a component - the app will then display the chosen component branded according to the selected brand. I want both of these options to be included in the URL.

The two dropdown's that are programatically changing the route. I am getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined whenever the user interacts with either dropdown.

I have a component being rendered by a route :

```
<Route path="/:brand/:component"
render={props => <DisplayComponent {...props} />} />
```

That component has two event handlers for two dropdown component that let the user select the root:

```
  handleComponentPick(event: any) {
    const component = event.target.value;
    this.props.history.push(`/${this.props.match.params.brand}/${component}`);
  }

  handleBrandChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const brand = event.target.value;
      this.props.history.push(`/${brand}/${this.props.match.params.component}`);
    }
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className={"constrain-width-wide center "}>
        <ThemePicker
          component={this.props.match.params.component}
          brand={this.props.match.params.brand}
          handleBrandChange={this.handleBrandChange}
          handleComponentPick={this.handleComponentPick}
        />
        <div className="currently-selected-component" />
        <Route path="/:brand/button" component={Button} />
        <Route path="/:brand/card" component={Card} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

I am wrapping the whole app in the `Router`.

````
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);```
````

Comment: please check what is this referring to inside handleComponentPick method.. You might need to bind it in the constructor first.

Comment: handleComponentPick doesn't seem to be bound to the class context

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, yup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982008/react-router-cannot-read-property-history-of-undefined/54982063#54982063 this should fix it. Cause it doesnt find the `props` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try these following changes
`handleComponentPick(event: any) {` to `handleComponentPick = (event: any) => {`
then
`render = () => {` to `render() {`
Hope this works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error inside a test using `jest`, you need to wrap your componen within a router. I am using [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library), so my logic looks as follows:

```js
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import YourComponent from '../path/to/YourComponent'

// ...
describe('YourComponent component', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup)
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(
      // The following will solve this issue
      <Router>
        <YourComponent />
      </Router>
    )
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the history like

```
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
```

that way, you can use history with props to navigate.

font: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md

try to use browserHistory on you app.js, like

```
render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='features' component={Features} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

that way, you are passing history for all of your another router.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass `history` as a prop to `Router`. I am expecting that you are using react router v4 aka `react-router-dom`.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";


const history = createBrowserHistory();

    ... 

<Router history={history}>
     <Routes />
</Router>
```

Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/yv5y905ojv

Answer (score 0):

Spied on the `useHistory()` hook and provided the mock route data.

```
import routeData from 'react-router';

describe('<Component /> container tests', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockHistory = {
      pathname: '/dashboard'
    };
    jest.spyOn(routeData, 'useHistory').mockReturnValue(mockHistory);
  });
```